# Using regular expressions in Python to find specific word

Tags: python, python-re

I have following lines (the order of lines can be different, there can be other similar lines as well). And I would like to replace `"sid"` with `"tempvalue"` taking into an account that `"sid"` can be surrounded by any symbol except for letters and digits. How to do that on Python using regular expression?

```
lines = [
 "VAR0=sid_host1; -",
 "VAR1=sid; -",
 "VAR2=psid; -",
 "VAR3=sid_host1; -",
 "VAR4=psid_host2; -",
 "VAR5 = (file=/dir1/sid_host1/sid/trace/alert_sid.log)(database=sid)"
]
```

For line 0 desired result is: `"VAR0=tempvalue_host1; -"`

for line 1: `"VAR1=tempvalue; -"`

for line 3: `"VAR3=tempvalue_host1; -"`

for line 5: `"VAR5 = (file=/dir1/tempvalue_host1/tempvalue/trace/alert_tempvalue.log)(database=tempvalue)"`

Other lines must remain untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can just do a regex replace all on `(?<![^\W_])sid(?![^\W_])` here:

```py
lines = [
    "VAR0=sid_host1; -",
    "VAR1=sid; -",
    "VAR2=psid; -",
    "VAR3=sid_host1; -",
    "VAR4=psid_host2; -",
    "VAR5 = (file=/dir1/sid_host1/sid/trace/alert_sid.log)(database=sid)"
]

lines = [re.sub(r'(?<![^\W_])sid(?![^\W_])', 'tempvalue', x) for x in lines]
print(lines)

['VAR0=tempvalue_host1; -',
 'VAR1=tempvalue; -',
 'VAR2=psid; -',
 'VAR3=tempvalue_host1; -',
 'VAR4=psid_host2; -',
 'VAR5 = (file=/dir1/tempvalue_host1/tempvalue/trace/alert_tempvalue.log)(database=tempvalue)']
```

Explanation of regex:

- `(?<![^\W_])` preceding character is either a non word OR underscore
- `sid` match literal `sid`
- `(?![^\W_])` following character is either a non word OR underscore

Note that we are basically building our own custom word boundaries which admit either `\W` or underscore (usually underscore is a word character).